# cant understand the calculation of return statement of binary program with recursion in c

Tags: function, recursion, binary, return

Program of binary conversion with recursion

it is working fine but i cant understand the meaning of one statement

Can any one help me to explain following

return (num % 2) + 10 * binary_conversion(num / 2);
while having input of 13

i am lil confused getting like this num =13;
13%2 = 1 + 10 * 6 = 66 , something stupid like calculation

```
int binary_conversion(int);

int main()
{
   int num, bin;

   printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
   scanf("%d", &num);
   bin = binary_conversion(num);
   printf("The binary equivalent of %d is %d\n", num, bin);
}

int binary_conversion(int num)
{
    if (num == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return (num % 2) + 10 * binary_conversion(num / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that `binary_conversion(6)` yields 6 in the example that's confusing you?  It will actually return `110` if you track through the recursive logic of that call. Your top level calculation will therefore be `1 + 10 * 110 = 1 + 1100 = 1101` which is, in fact, the binary representation of 13.  I leave it to you to track back why `binary_conversion(6)` yields `110`.  You'll find that along the way you have to call `binary_conversion()` recursively with arguments 3, 1, and 0, just as you had to call it with an argument of 6 to solve for 13.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusions stems from not understanding the operation of recursion.  It's time to interview the function with **print** statements.  This will allow you to follow the control and data flow of the routine.

```
int binary_conversion(int num)
{
    printf("ENTER num = %d\n", num);
    if (num == 0)
    {
        printf("BASE CASE returns 0\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("RECURSION: new bit = %d, recur on %d\n", num % 2, num / 2);
        return (num % 2) + 10 * binary_conversion(num / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: still not getting what is going with binary_conversion(6) yields 110 ??

Comment: thanks for the answer but would you clear me binary_conversion(6) yields 110

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Or are you still confused?  If so, please show the output from your debugging run and a specific way in which that output confuses you.  These updates should go into your original question.

Comment: now i understand but the answer is going on 1011 but it yields 1101 so its mean that it is printing a reverse value so why is this so happening ?
i think due to recursion ?

Comment: Again, please show the output from your debugging run, etc.